# WinRT Xaml ListViewItem alternating background color

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, listviewitem

I need to make a ListView alternates the background colors of its rows. I had tried a lot of things and nothing work for me.

The first row must be with a white background, the second must be black, the third white again and so on.

Does anyone know a simple way to do it? I'm sure there's a simple solution as it's a regular feature.

I'm developing WinRT app with C#, and had tried selectors, converters..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this at runtime using following code if your listview is already populated.  Additional formatting will probably be required in the template of the ListView for padding and what not.

```
        int i = 1;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
                item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
            }
            else
            {
                item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
                item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding color_background}"/>
```

just add the property to the collection of elements in ListView